# Excel VBA checking if workbook is opened and opening it if not

Tags: vba, excel

code I put below is not working properly. I am getting error 400 when try to run macro. Could you take a little review of this code? I am not sure if problem is not with function variable I am refering to.

```
Sub AutoFinal()    
    Dim final_wb As Workbook, shop_stat_wb As Workbook 
    Dim book2 As String
    book2 = "Workbook_I_need.xlsx"
    Dim book2path As String
    book2path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & book2
    Set final_wb = ThisWorkbook
    If IsOpen(book2) = False Then Workbooks.Open (book2path)
    Set shop_stat_wb = Workbooks(book2)    
End Sub

Function IsOpen(strWkbNm As String) As Boolean    
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Set wBook = Workbooks(strWkbNm)

    If wBook Is Nothing Then    'Not open
        IsOpen = False
        Set wBook = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        IsOpen = True
        Set wBook = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If    
End Function
```

Comment: What line does it error on?

Comment: I would guess the error appears on the line with Workbooks.Open. Set a breakpoint there, and check that the Path is correct, and it refers to an existing file.

Comment: @z32a7ul Yes you are right about the error line. I've checked a path an it is correct. Setting up breakpoint is not a problem, but what I can achieve with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IsOpen` can be simplified:

```
Function IsOpen(strWkbNm As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks(strWkbNm)
    IsOpen = Err.Number = 0
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

Here is how I would write it:

```
Sub AutoFinal2()
    Dim final_wb As Workbook, shop_stat_wb As Workbook
    Dim WorkbookFullName As String

    WorkbookFullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & book2
    Set final_wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set shop_stat_wb = getWorkbook(WorkbookFullName)

    If shop_stat_wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "File not found:" & vbCrLf & WorkbookFullName, vbCritical, "AutoFinal2 Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Function getWorkbook(WorkbookFullName As String) As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.FullName = WorkbookFullName Then Exit For
    Next

    If wb Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Dir(WorkbookFullName)) > 0 Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(WorkbookFullName)
        End If
    End If
    Set getWorkbook = wb
End Function
```

Comment: @Thomsa Inzina    Thanks a lot for this code! I like they way u did this, anyway you are referring to book2 not declared. But putting 2 additional lines solved a problem. According to IsOpen function, variable strWKbNm should be put also in my Sub() to work properly?