# Macro referencing incorrect workbook when workbook is open

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub ShipReportPopulate(TicketDataCollection, TicketArray)

Dim Shipwb As Workbook
Dim ShipWS As Worksheet
Dim NamedRng As String
Dim FN As String
FN = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Shipping Report.xlsx"

Set Shipwb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FN)
Set ShipWS = Shipwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

PopRow = ShipWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1


For i = 1 To UBound(TicketDataCollection)
    NamedRng = TicketDataCollection(i, 6)
    With ShipWS
        .Cells(PopRow, ShipWS.Range("Date").Column) = TicketArray(1)
        'Application.Goto ShipWS.Range("Customer")
        .Cells(PopRow, ShipWS.Range("Customer").Column) = TicketArray(2)
        .Cells(PopRow, ShipWS.Range("TicketNum").Column) = TicketArray(3)
        .Cells(PopRow, ShipWS.Range("Key").Column) = TicketDataCollection(i, 1)
        .Cells(PopRow, ShipWS.Range("Product").Column) = TicketDataCollection(i, 4)
        .Cells(PopRow, ShipWS.Range("Weight").Column) = TicketDataCollection(i, 8)
        .Cells(PopRow, ShipWS.Range("Footage").Column) = TicketDataCollection(i, 7)
        .Cells(PopRow, ShipWS.Range("Type").Column) = TicketDataCollection(i, 9)
        'If primary category is footage then populate footage, else weight
        If TicketDataCollection(i, 5) = "F" Then
            .Cells(PopRow, ShipWS.Range(NamedRng).Column) = TicketDataCollection(i, 7)
        Else
            .Cells(PopRow, ShipWS.Range(NamedRng).Column) = TicketDataCollection(i, 8)
        End If
    End With
    PopRow = PopRow + 1
Next i

'Shipwb.Close

End Sub
```

I am getting the error in this line

```
Set ShipWS = Shipwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Error only occurs when the 'Shipwb' workbook is already open, and when I uncomment the 'Shipwb.Close' function then everything works fine - but I would like to keep the workbook open and be able to run this function multiple times. I have tried deleting and renaming the named range but it has not worked.

I am out of ideas, what could be causing this problem? Thanks in advance for the help.

UPDATE:

I think the real problem is that when workbooks are open and I run the code again the macro refers to 'RoyalWS' instead of 'ShipWS'. My subs are as follows:

```
Sub Main()
'Some stuff here
Call ShipReportPopulate(TicketDataCollection, TicketArray)
Call RoyaltyReportPopulate(TicketDataCollection, TicketArray)
End Sub
```

Where

```
Sub RoyaltyReportPopulate(TicketDataCollection As Variant, TicketArray As Variant)

Dim Royalwb As Workbook
Dim RoyalWS As Worksheet
Dim NamedRng As String
Dim FN2 As String
FN2 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Royalty Report.xlsx"

Set Royalwb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FN2)
Set RoyalWS = Royalwb.Sheets("Sheet2")

PopRow = RoyalWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2

For i = 1 To UBound(TicketDataCollection)
    NamedRng = TicketDataCollection(i, 3)
    Sum = 0
    For j = 1 To UBound(TicketDataCollection)
        If TicketDataCollection(i, 3) = TicketDataCollection(j, 3) Then
            Sum = Sum + TicketDataCollection(j, 8)
        End If
    Next j
    RoyalWS.Cells(PopRow, RoyalWS.Range(NamedRng).Column).Value = Sum
Next i

With RoyalWS
    .Cells(PopRow, RoyalWS.Range("Date").Column).Value = TicketArray(1)
    .Cells(PopRow, RoyalWS.Range("TicketNum").Column).Value = TicketArray(3)
End With

'Royalwb.Close

End Sub
```

How do I ensure that the macro is referring to the correct workbook?

UPDATE 2:

Okay so initially I had both 'ShipWS' and 'RoyalWS' refer to "Sheet1" on their respective workbooks. I have modified it as per the code above and am now getting "Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range" here

```
Set ShipWS = Shipwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Saying that "ShipWS" is Nothing

Comment: Are you sure you want to be executing a function and not a Macro?

Comment: You're right, this should be a Macro instead I will fix that

Comment: In your updated code, you don't assign any value (Workbook) to the `Shipwb` variable, hence, ShipWS is nothing and you'll get an Object Required error.

Comment: Sorry @DavidZemens, can you explain please? The error still occurs in the same snippet of code that was posted pre-update. The flow of code occurs as such: sub main -> sub ShipReportPopulate -> sub RoyaltyReportPopulate. In ShipReportPopulate I assign Shipwb as a workbook

Comment: I'd recommend for you to be less condescending and more helpful as your comment has not provided any clarity, you could have provided an example instead of a paragraph. I clearly set Shipwb in the code here

`Dim Shipwb As Workbook`
`Set Shipwb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FN)`

Comment: I'd recommend that you revise your question to show your current code (and only your current code). Anyone who wants to see the edit history can see that easily enough. But generally it's not terribly helpful to include a mish-mash of various failed attempts, in fact it makes it harder to follow your comments as it's not always clear what part of what code and what attempt you're referring to.

Comment: Could we try to distill your problem in to a clear and concise problem statement? Something like, "How can I determine if a workbook is already open, and if it's not, open it?".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set Shipwb = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook
```

This will only store the reference to your workbook instead of opening it, so you shouldn't need the

```
Shipwb.Close
```

Update:

Try detecting if the workbook is open. I stole some code from the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708491/excel-vba-checking-if-workbook-is-opened-and-opening-it-if-not) thread.

```
Function IsOpen(strWkbNm As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks(strWkbNm)
    IsOpen = Err.Number = 0
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Here's how I would implement this into your function:

```
Function ShipReportPopulate(TicketDataCollection, TicketArray)
    Dim open As Boolean
    Dim Shipwb As Workbook
    Dim ShipWS As Worksheet
    Dim NamedRng As String
    Dim FN As String
    FN = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Shipping Report.xlsx"

    open = IsOpen(FN)
    If open Then
        'closes the workbook
        Excel.Application.Workbooks(FN).Close (SaveChanges:=True)
        Set Shipwb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FN)
        Set ShipWS = Shipwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

        'do the thing here
    ElseIf Not open Then
        Set Shipwb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FN)
        Set ShipWS = Shipwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

        'do the thing here
    End If
End Function
```

Because this detects if the workbook you want to open is open, then you could just put Shipwb.Close at the very end. Your call.

Comment: Thing is, I am not populating the values in ThisWorkbook - I have a Sub calling multiple Functions that open various workbooks and populate items from ThisWorkbook

Comment: Thank you, I'll use this if nothing else works - I just don't want to needlessly open and close workbooks. This slows the code a lot and creates a lot of screen popups, not to mention bypassing the workbook saving features

Comment: There is an argument in the Close() method that allows you to save the workbook. I'll edit that in for you.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike that method of calling named ranges. You can deal with the object in a much more direct fashion, like so:

```
wb.names("NameHere").RefersToRange
```

Gets the range, then of course

```
wb.names("NameHere").RefersToRange.value2
```

Gets the value

No need to deal with (possibly changing) worksheet names

Comment: I will try this, will update once I change the code - thanks

Comment: @Selkie: What if "NameHere" is a worksheet name instead of a workbook name? Still must understand sheets in the book.

Comment: Ah - I tend to religiously avoid worksheet-scoped names. They cause a huge amount of trouble, for very little benefit. Worse-case, I append the type of name to the name - For example, "Financials_GroupA" instead of a worksheet scoped name of "Financials" in the tab "GroupA"

Comment: @Selkie I like what you have mentioned and will implement just because it is tidier - however my initial problem is not fixed, refer to my updated question please

Comment: I re-read your question - what's the error message that you're getting?

Comment: Are you sure, SURE that your name is correct? Checking that error message, it boils down to "Couldn't find that named range". Check for spaces, check for underscores, etc.

Comment: Yes the names are correct, it works perfectly if the workbooks are closed - but if they are open then the problem starts to happen. If the names were not correct then it wouldn't run when the workbooks are closed